# Paypal is not sending notifications

Tags: php, paypal

I am using PHP REST APIv1 (I believe) to integrate with paypal.

My request code looks as follows:

```
include '../../classes/db.connect.php';
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;

require 'bootstrap.php';
if (empty($_POST['buy_now'])) {
  throw new Exception('This script should not be called directly, expected post data');
}
$setitem = strip_tags($_POST['item']);
$stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM shopping WHERE id = :id");
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $setitem);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();

$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');
  $currency = 'USD';
  $amountPayable = $row['price'];
  $item1 = new Item();
  $item1->setName($row['name'])
    ->setCurrency('USD')
    ->setQuantity('1')
    ->setPrice($amountPayable);

$invoiceNumber = uniqid();
$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency($currency)
  ->setTotal($amountPayable);

$itemList = new ItemList();
if (isset($item1) && isset($item2)) {
  $itemList->setItems(array($item1, $item2));
} elseif (isset($item1)) {
  $itemList->setItems(array($item1));
} elseif (isset($item2)) {
  $itemList->setItems(array($item2));
}

$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount)
  ->setItemList($itemList)
  ->setDescription('Website '.$row['name'].' Purchase')
  ->setInvoiceNumber($invoiceNumber)
  ->setNotifyUrl("https://REDACTED/notify.php")
  ->setCustom($username);

$redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl($paypalConfig['return_url'])
  ->setCancelUrl($paypalConfig['cancel_url']);

$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent('sale')
  ->setPayer($payer)
  ->setTransactions([$transaction])
  ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);

try {
  $payment->create($apiContext);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  throw new Exception('Unable to create link for payment');
}
header('location:' . $payment->getApprovalLink());
```

A payment goes through just fine, but notify_url is not called by paypal. There are no errors at all. The user can make a payment, the payment goes through, the user is returned to `setReturnUrl` but `setNotifyUrl` seems to get ignored.

I have done a var_dump on `$transaction` and the `notify_url` is sent to paypal, but it is not called by paypal - thus I get no notifications of transactions/nothing updated in the database.

I have done the most basic test I can think to ensure paypal is not calling `notify_url`. The php in the file is simply set to:

```
include '../../classes/db.connect.php';
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO test (info) VALUES ('1122')");
$stmt->execute();
```

I realize REST is intended to work with webhooks - but I am not wanting to use them for several various reasons. My understanding is that setting a notify_url will allow paypal to use that url as an IPN. However I am finding paypal is just ignoring this variable.

Also I should mention I have tried this with IPN enabled and IPN status updates disabled, I have tried with IPN enabled and status updates enabled, and I have tried it with IPN disabled. All three ways has the same result - no errors, everything work, but no notifications sent nor received by paypal.

My IPN istory page on paypal is completely empty.

Am I doing something wrong? Misunderstanding something?

I cannot find any solid information about this.

Comment: "My understanding is that setting a notify_url will allow paypal to use that url as an IPN. However I am finding paypal is just ignoring this variable. "

You should contact PayPal's support to ask about this issue, since only they will know what is happening in a particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Paypal IPNs setup through your Paypal account are sent irrespective of the method used to create the transactions.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/

You can use the IPN simulator to test your receiving code, or by signing up for a sandbox account as configuring the IPN setting there.

Comment: Configuring IPNs at the transaction level is generally a more robust integration (since the shopping cart/order manager has direct control in case of a domain change, etc) and it will take precedence over any default IPN handler set or not set at the account level, so I don't think this answer adds much -- except perhaps as an alternate solution if he's not able to get the preferred method working.

Comment: I don't think you can set a notify url with the rest API afaik.

Comment: `notify_url` is in the `transaction` object https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#definition-transaction

Comment: @PrestonPHX It's the version 1 (deprecated) not the 2...

Comment: The OP said they were using v1/payments, so I linked to that.  v2/checkout/orders does not allow setting notify_url, since IPN is a very old and clunky technology. One should transition to using webhooks with v2 instead.